# WooCommerce Auto Assign Product Category using If Else Statement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

For woocommerce gurus, I've 4 product categories called A, B , C, D with respective category ID 1,2,3,4.

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. If product category A is checked, category B will auto not checked without affecting other categories.
2. If product category A is unchecked, category B will auto checked without affecting other categories.

Based on this post, [Automatically assign products to a defined product category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304421/automatically-assign-products-to-a-defined-product-category-in-woocommerce) , I wrote these codes.

```
// Only on WooCommerce Product edit pages (Admin)
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_add_product_category', 50, 3 );
function auto_add_product_category( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products

// If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return $post_id;

// Check the user's permissions.
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

$term_id = 2; // <== Your targeted product category term ID
$term_id2 = 1; // <== Your targeted product category term ID
$taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // The taxonomy for Product category

// If the product has not "93" category id and if "93" category exist
if ( ! has_term( $term_id2, 'product_cat', $post_id ) && term_exists( $term_id2, $taxonomy ) )
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term_id, $taxonomy, true ); // we set this product category
else
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term_id, $taxonomy, false );
}
```

The number 2 working fine, but for number 1, this is what happen:

1. If product category A is checked, category A and all other categories will uncheck except for category B.

Any idea what wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$term_id_A = 1,
$term_id_B = 2;
//get all the terms:
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'product_cat' );
//just their IDs:
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );

if(in_array($term_id_A, $term_ids) && ($key = array_search($term_id_B, $term_ids)) !== false) {
    unset($term_ids[$key]);
} elseif(!in_array($term_id_A, $term_ids) && !in_array($term_id_B, $term_ids)) {
    $term_ids[] = $term_id_B;
}
wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $term_ids, 'product_cat');
```

Comment: Thank you that works! One question though, what if I want to add "If category A is checked, set product status to out of stock" ?

Comment: Do you want to create a new question for that>

Comment: orite, i'll create it later.